# Database structure replication in a "one-to-many database"

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm researching something that I'd like to call replication, but there is probably some other technical word for it - since as far as I know "replication" is a complete replication of structure and its data to slaves. I only want the structure replication. My terminology is probably wrong which is why I can't seem to find answers on my own.

Is it possible to set up a mysql environment that replicates a master structure to multiple local databases when a change, addition or drop has been made? I'm looking for a solution where each user gets its own database instance with their own unique data but with the same structure of tables. When an update is being made to the master structure, the same procedure should be replicated by each user database.

E.g. a column is being added to **master.table1** that is replicated by **user1.table1** and **user2.table1**.

My first idea was to write a update procedure in PHP but it feels like this would be a quite fundamental function built-in to the database, since my conclusion would be that index lookup would be much faster with less data (~ total data divided by users) and probably more secure (no unfortunate leaks, if any).

Comment: Would probably be a good idea, I just didn't know about that site.

Comment: Good luck with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with simple set of SQL scripts for every change in database, named year-month-day-description.sql, which i run in lexicographical order (that's why it begins with date).

Of course you do not want to run them all every time. So to know which scripts I need to execute, each script has simple insert at it's end, which inserts filename of the script into table in database. So the updater PHP script simply make list of scripts, remove these in table and run the rest.

Good on this solution is, that you can include data transformations too. And also, it can be fully automatic and as long as scripts are ok, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Agreed; I use something similar, except I use a database "version" stored in a database table. All the CREATE/ALTER/DROP/etc statements are in an array in a PHP file which is executed when needed; the array index is the 'version'.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, but how do you verify the integrity of the migration? Do you dump the development schema and use it as a template to match the updated "migrated" schema for validation?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to look into incorporating the use of database "migrations", something popularized by the Ruby on Rails framework.  [This Google search for PHP database migrations](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rails%20database%20migrations%20for%20PHP&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) might be a could starting point for you.

The concept is that as you develop your application and make schema changes, you can create SQL migration scripts to roll-forward or roll-back the schema changes.  This makes it really easy to then easily "migrate" your database schema to work with a particular code version (for example if you have branched code being worked on in multiple environments that need each need a different version of the database).

That isn't going to autmoatically make updates like you suggest, but is certainly a step in the right direction.  There a also tools like Toad for MySQL and Navicat which have some level of support of schema synchronization. But again these would be manual comparisons/syncs.